# Flexbox - don't overflow container vertically

Tags: css, flexbox

I mostly get flexbox but I seem to be missing a concept. What I want is something like this

[image: Blocks stacking out sideways]

Basically I don't want the page to overflow vertically and all those red blocks to stack vertically and wrap horizontally - overflowing and scrolling the screen horizontally if needed *but never vertically*.

The problem is that I don't know how to set the height of the red section's container to be "the rest of the height available on the screen". `height: 100%` doesn't work, even with flexbox it seems to be tied to screen width. I can of course hard-set it to a pixel number but that is wrong since different screens can be different sizes.

[This is the jsbin template for what I'm doing](http://jsbin.com/kadawuvujo/1/edit?html,css,output). I can set `body: 100vh` but then the body's contents overflow stretching downward, and I don't know how to set the main height as I specified above.

Comment: Try removing `flex-direction: column;` from `div.container`

Comment: @Pangloss that would force stacking horizontally and wrapping vertically. I specifically want the opposite. If I did that, not only would all the blocks be in the wrong order, but if they overflowed the screen would push out vertically, **not** horizontally.

Comment: OK, still don't understand the question fully, but how about this? http://jsfiddle.net/bez1a3L0/

Comment: @Pangloss you set `main { height: 100vh}` but note that overflows vertically because now the total height is main (exactly the page height) plus whatever preceded it vertically (the nav bar in this case). This is exactly the issue I am talking about in the question. It needs to not overflow vertically at all but without an explicit width set for main - just "take up the rest of the vertical space".

Comment: So apart from the height issue, are all the red blocks looking good in that fiddle?

Comment: Yup - but I figured that much out myself. I even considered doing a `calc` to subtract out the height of the nav bar, but I don't necessarily know it in real life. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Does this look better? http://jsfiddle.net/bez1a3L0/1/ almost the same like you said.

Comment: @Pangloss umm...I just explained why that doesn't work in my previous comment. You're assuming a height for the preceding content, but you can't possibly know that for sure (it could flex in response to content and screen width itself). This isn't an "OMG I just need to get this working" question. This is a "what flexbox concept am I missing" question.

Comment: As far as I know column + wrap flexbox doesn't work as we expected, it's either a bug or not supported yet or it's just designed like that I guess. Your whole question can be simplified like this I imagine http://jsfiddle.net/vcdvap5p/ It simply won't work without the height to set.

Comment: @Pangloss the problem with that simplification is that you can fix it with `.container { height: 100vh }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<body>` and `<html>` tags by default are only as tall as their content. So to flex vertically from the top of the viewport to the bottom you need to set them both to have `height: 100%`.

<s>Beyond that, you have uncovered an implementation bug with flexbox. The code below works as expected in Safari but is broken in Chrome and Firefox.</s>

**UPDATE:** As described by Daniel Holbert here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1212058 This behavior is actually due to the newly implemented `min-height: auto` behavior. The code below has been updated to work correctly in all browsers that support modern flexbox.

```css
* { margin:0; padding:0 }

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

nav {
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 5px
}

nav.top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  flex: none;
}

div.main {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

nav.side {
  width: 70px;
  height: 400px;
  flex: none;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 0;
}

div.container {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  min-height: 0;
}

section {
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 5px;
}



aside {
  outline: 1px solid darkgreen;
  flex: none;
  height: 50px;
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav class="top"></nav>
  <div class="main">
      <nav class="side"></nav>
      <main>
          <div class="container">
              <section></section>
              <section></section>
              <section></section>
              <section></section>
              <section></section>
          </div> 
          <aside>
              <button>Cancel</button>
              <button>Save</button>
          </aside>
      </main>
  </div>
</body>
```

*NOTE: To see the column wrapping you’ll want to click “Full page” in the snippet*

Comment: son of a... works in IE too for what that's worth. What specifically is being buggy here?

Comment: @GeorgeMauer don't you want to red blocks to wrap? but I don't see any of them wrapping.

Comment: @Pangloss look at it in IE or (I assume) Safari.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer don't have IE to test, but no wrapping on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @Pangloss right, that's exactly what Zaqx is saying - conceptually this should work but there's an implementation bug in Chrome (and I guess Firefox)

Comment: @GeorgeMauer haven’t looked into it very deeply yet but it looks like `<main>` is not calculating its available space correctly.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer can't imagine it's simply because you forgot to set html to height:100%, anyway if it works for you then great, but if it don't work on both chrome+firefox then can you use it for production.

Comment: @Pangloss yes, setting height to 100vh was necessary, but no - that wasn't the bug. It's the `div.main { flex: 1 }` This expands the div properly in the vertical direction on IE but not on Chrome.

Comment: @Pangloss issue isolated and reported: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=539970&thanks=539970&ts=1444159059

Comment: @GeorgeMauer thanks for doing that, hopefully it can get fixed soon.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer You did the right thing. We have two bugs for Chrome now which is a little frustrating for me, perhaps particularly because you didn’t know what the issue was before I told you, but… don’t worry about it. It’s always right to assume the other guy might not file it. Chrome: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=539983 Firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1212058

Comment: I suppose it’s also a bit frustrating because I wouldn’t of spent a bunch of time isolating this out if I knew you were on it.

Comment: Sorry about that. If its any consolation - I just spent an hour on yet **another** chrome bug - apparently flexbox doesn't work with fieldset elements in chrome. It's turning out to be quite a day...

Comment: @GeorgeMauer turns out this is actually expected behavior based on some new changes to the flexbox spec. See updated answer above.

Comment: Thanks so much for updating me!